# How to check item size and move them if they are over a certain threshold in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm currently working on a Powershell script that is supposed to do the following:
Check all items in a folder, if there are any items over a certain size (let's say 10MB) create a folder (named "toobig") and move those items there.

Here is my script so far:

```
function delbig {

param (
[parameter (Mandatory=$true)]
 $p
)


$a= Get-ChildItem $p | Where-Object {$_.Length -gt 10000000} | Measure- Object
$a.count


if ($a -gt 0){

    mkdir "$p\tooBig"

}

"$([int]$a)"

}
delbig
```

I've figured out how to move the items and how to create the folder but my if condition to decide if the actions should be triggered is giving me the following error:

```
Cannot compare "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericMeasureInfo" because it is not IComparable.
At C:\Powertest\movbig.ps1:14 char:1
+ if ($a -gt 0){
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotIcomparable

Cannot convert the "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericMeasureInfo" value of type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericMeasureInfo" to type "System.Int32".
At C:\Powertest\movbig.ps1:20 char:4
+ "$([int]$a)"
+    ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConvertToFinalInvalidCastException
```

So the value in $a should be an int right? And my if condition is supposed to look if the value is greater than 0 (I've tried it with "0" as well).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Regards, Gerfi

Answer (score 4):

`$a` is an instance of a `GenericMeasureInfo` type, which can't be compared to zero (an int).  Use the `Count` property of `$a` to compare to zero:

```
if ($a.Count -gt 0){
    mkdir "$p\tooBig" 
}
```

Also, I noticed there is a space in `Measure- Object` which needs to be removed.  I'm guessing that's just a typo in the post.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help with the included explanation! Learning this really feels like an uphill battle for me, so I'm very thank full for people like you helping me out! It worked!
And yes the space was just a typo in the post.

Comment: @Gerfi - Mark this as the answer if it resolved your issue. It helps promote helpful people and makes the correct answer easily identified by people reading this post for their own learning. :)

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:

```
function Move-BigFiles {
    param([parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$Path)

    $tooBigFiles = Get-ChildItem $Path | Where-Object {$_.Length -gt 10MB}
    if ($tooBigFiles) {
        $dest = mkdir "$Path\TooBig" -Force
        $tooBigFiles | Move-Item -Destination $dest
    }
}
```

PowerShell conditions can use 'truthy' values. Any nonempty collection is interpreted as `$true`.

The problem with your script is type mismatch. `$a` is object of type `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericMeasureInfo`, as a result of Measure-Object call. It can't be compared to `int` value.

Comment: I've tried that and am getting this:

Move-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Powertest\delbig\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GenericMeasureInfo' because it does not exist.
At C:\Powertest\movbig.ps1:21 char:20
+     $toobigfiles | Move-Item -Destination "$p\tooBig"
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Powertest\de...ericMeasureInfo:String) [Move-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand

Comment: Sorry cant seem to find how to mark my comment as code

Comment: What is `$p`? Filter? Subdirectory? How do you execute this function?

Comment: $p ist just the path where the script does its thing

Comment: Oh, I understand. Now "full-featured" version is available. Should work out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both very much, with your help I now got the script to do what I want it to:

```
function delbig {

param (
[parameter (Mandatory=$true)]
 $p
)


$toobigfiles= Get-ChildItem $p | Where-Object {$_.Length -gt 10000000} | Measure-Object
$toobigfiles.count


if ($toobigfiles.Count -gt "0"){

    mkdir "$p\tooBig"
}


$toobigfiles= Get-ChildItem $p | Where-Object {$_.Length -gt 10000000}

if ($toobigfiles.Count -gt "0"){

    $toobigfiles | Move-Item -Destination "$p\tooBig"
}

#"$toobigfiles"


}
delbig
```

This is the first time I wrote a script largely on my own and I'm very happy :)
(Started learning Powershell about a week ago and have never written a line of any code in my life)